# Am I doing this join right? Three way table join

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join

Im trying to join three tables in the following format.

```
select * 
from A 
inner join
B (inner join (C on C.id=B.c_id))

on A.id=B.a_id;
```

Ive never used a lookup table to perform a join (in this case B).

Oracle throws an error saying

```
ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 6 Column: 11
```

Any insight on where Im going wrong would be appreciated .
Thanks!

Comment: The title is quite meaningless,  pleaae fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather try something like

```
SELECT *
FROM A INNER JOIN
B ON A.id = B.a_id INNER JOIN
C ON C.id = B.c_id
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be written like this, which is clearer:

```
select * 
from A 
inner join B on A.id=b.a_id 
inner join C on C.id=B.c_id
```

You can see how this shows the intent of your statement (the join clause is very explicit about how you want to join the tables) Vs joining 2 tables by expressing the join condition in the where clause (as in `where a.id=b.id`)

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from A 
inner join B on A.id=B.a_id
inner join C on C.id=B.c_id
```